# How to send radio button's value into state and change the value when another radio button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to push the value of selected radio button in component into the state on the page, such that when another radio button is selected, it updates the value in the state with the newly selected value.
The problem is, whenever I change the selected radio button, it is adding a new value instead of updating it.

This is my page

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Popconfirm, Icon, Input, Radio, Collapse, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import Axios from 'axios';
import CompanyContext from '../util/UserContext';
import renderEmpty from 'antd/lib/config-provider/renderEmpty';
import InputOnly from '../components/InputOnly';
import CustomInput from '../components/Input';
import Lampiran from '../components/Lampiran';
import CustomCheckBox from '../components/CheckBox';

export default function Hitung() {

    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    let [form, setForm] = useState([]);
    let [soal, setSoal] = useState([]);
    let [pilihan, setPilihan] = useState([]);
    let [test, setTest] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    let [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");

    let [coba, setCoba] = useState([]);
    let [coba2, setCoba2] = useState([]);

    const company = useContext(CompanyContext);
    let answertemp = []

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            try {
                let data = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/lelang/getquestion');
                setSoal(data.data.pertanyaan);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    function onAnswer(data) {
        answertemp.push(data);
        console.log(answertemp);
    }




    function RenderQuestion() {
        if (soal.length != 0) {
            return soal.map(data => {
                switch (data.type_question) {
                    case "input":
                        return (<CustomInput data={data} onAnswer={onAnswer} />)
                    case "input_only":
                        return (<InputOnly data={data} onAnswer={answer => {
                            if(coba.length!=0){
                                for(let i =0;i<coba.length;i++){
                                    if (coba[i].id_question===answer.id_question){
                                        coba[i].answer=answer.answer;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else if (i<coba.length-1){
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        setCoba([...coba,answer])
                                    }                       
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log('add');
                                setCoba([...coba,answer])
                            }

                        }} />)
                    case "lampiran":
                        return (<Lampiran data={data} onAnswer={onAnswer} />)
                    case "checkbox":
                        return (<CustomCheckBox data={data} onAnswer={onAnswer} />)
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            return (<h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Loading....</h2>)
        }
    }


    //insert_answer

    async function submit(e) {
        setAnswer(answertemp)
        setLoading(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const token = await Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/lelang/insert_answer', company.data);

        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("error " + e)
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Input Penilaian {company.data}</h1>
            <div style={{ padding: '30px' }}>
                <Form>
                    {RenderQuestion()}
                    <button onClick={() => console.log(coba)}>Simpan</button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is the component

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {  Radio, Input, Form } from 'antd';


export default function CustomInput (props){
    let[radioInput,setRadioInput]=useState({});
    let[chooseInput, setChooseInput] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
        setRadioInput(props.data);
    },[]);



    return (
        <div>
        <p style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{radioInput.question}</p>
        <Form.Item required>
            <Radio.Group 
             options = {radioInput.variable}
             onChange={(data) => props.onAnswer(data.target.value)}
             onClick={data => props.onAnswer(data.radioInput.value)}
             >

            </Radio.Group>
            </Form.Item>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dependencies in effect to listen tho changes. When sending empty array in dependencies, hook will happen only on first render. In your case change the use effect to

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setRadioInput(props.data);
},[props.data]);
```

Comment: i've change the useEffect but it still adding new value to the state instead of changing it